# Jquery Flip toggle switch UI is not looking as 'slider-switch' instead it is shown as drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, knockout.js

I am using select tag with `data-role='slider'` for slider switch but instead it is coming as `'drop down' select`. After investigating I found that in normal scenarios , extra `div` with `data-role=application` is generated , which gives toggle switch look and feel. But that extra `div` is not getting generated in my application

Find the code

```
<select data-theme="b" class="selectElement" 
        data-bind="jqmFlip:chargeble" data-role="slider">
    <option value="false">No</option>
    <option value="true">Yes</option>
</select>
```

Also I am using require.js for loading js files, can that affect?

Comment: I tried your code with jquery 1.9.1, jquery ui 1.9.2 and jQuery Mobile 1.3.0b1..I don't see any issue...check this..http://jsfiddle.net/V6RsX/1/  which versions are you using ?

Comment: Yeah , but if you notice in inspect element  extra div role ='application' is generated below select tag. Outside my current project it works. But somehow in my project it is not. I am using 'knockout' and require.js as well, can that affect?